# Convert sequence of longitude and latitude to polygon via sf in R

Tags: r, r-sf

I have five longitude and latitude that form a shape like this.

```
df <- c(order=1:5,
        lon=c(119.4,119.4,119.4,119.5,119.5), 
        lat=c(-5.192,-5.192,-5.187,-5.187,-5.191))
```

How could I easily convert them into an sf polygon data frame using `sf` package like this?

```
## Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 0 fields
## geometry type:  POLYGON
## dimension:      XY
## bbox:           xmin: 119.4 ymin: -5.192 xmax: 119.5 ymax: -5.187
## epsg (SRID):    4326
## proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
## geometry
## 1 POLYGON ((119.4 ...
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I saw that this question is coming up in search results, so I thought I'd provide a more flexible method of creating polygons in `sf` from a series of `lat` and `lon` coordinates.

`st_as_sf` has an argument `coords` that will take points given as coordinate columns in a data frame and convert those columns to `sf` `POINT` geometries. Then, because `sf` works well with `dplyr`, we can `st_combine` the points into a `MULTIPOINT` and `st_cast` to convert to `POLYGON`. Compared to "manual" construction with `st_polygon`, this has the advantage that we don't have to think so carefully about closing the ring or about the right level of nested lists to pass to the constructor, and that if we have more than one polygon in a set of coordinates we can use `group_by` to create all the polygons at once.

N.B. Technically you can do this with `do_union=FALSE` inside of `summarise`, but I think that this syntax is a bit clearer and more similar to normal `summarise`.

```r
df <- data.frame(
  lon = c(119.4, 119.4, 119.4, 119.5, 119.5),
  lat = c(-5.192, -5.192, -5.187, -5.187, -5.191)
)
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.6.1, GDAL 2.2.3, proj.4 4.9.3
polygon <- df %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = 4326) %>%
  summarise(geometry = st_combine(geometry)) %>%
  st_cast("POLYGON")
polygon
#> Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 0 fields
#> geometry type:  POLYGON
#> dimension:      XY
#> bbox:           xmin: 119.4 ymin: -5.192 xmax: 119.5 ymax: -5.187
#> epsg (SRID):    4326
#> proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
#>                         geometry
#> 1 POLYGON ((119.4 -5.192, 119...

plot(polygon)
```

[image]

Created on 2018-10-05 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: I don't seem able to `group_by` when I supply  a list of lon and lat. E.g. for two polygons I'm supplying a df as follows: `df <- tibble(AC_NO = c(100, 101),
  lon = list(c(76.4, 76.38, 76.4, 76.38), c(76.4, 76.38, 76.4, 76.38)), lat = list(c(9.58, 9.58, 9.56, 9.56), c(9.55, 9.55, 9.53, 9.53))`. And then: `df %>%
  group_by(AC_NO) %>% 
  st_as_sf(` etc. I get an error that "list" cannot be coerced to type "double". Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Necro, but it looks like you have list columns - unnesting would probably solve it. I realise I used the word "list" imprecisely above, changed it now

Answer (score 14):

The equivalent as @Yo B. answer but with `sf`

```
library(sf)
df <- data.frame(lon=c(119.4,119.4,119.4,119.5,119.5), 
                 lat=c(-5.192,-5.192,-5.187,-5.187,-5.191))

# You need first to close your polygon 
# (first and last points must be identical)
df <- rbind(df, df[1,])

poly <- st_sf(st_sfc(st_polygon(list(as.matrix(df)))), crs = 4326)
poly

## Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 0 fields
## geometry type:  POLYGON
## dimension:      XY
## bbox:           xmin: 119.4 ymin: -5.192 xmax: 119.5 ymax: -5.187
## epsg (SRID):    4326
## proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
##   st_sfc.st_polygon.list.as.matrix.df....
## 1          POLYGON ((119.4 -5.192, 119...
```

**edit to answer a question in the comments**

See the [main sf vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sf/vignettes/sf1.html) for a clear and detailed explanation of `sf`, `sfc` and `sfg` objects summarized as :

> The three classes used to represent simple features are:
>
> - sf, the table (data.frame) with feature attributes and feature geometries, which contains
> - sfc, the list-column with the geometries for each feature (record), which is composed of
> - sfg, the feature geometry of an individual simple feature.

The `st_sfc` function builds only the geometry column (which is a list of polygons - here with only one polygon). The "c" in `sfc` stands for "column". The function `st_sf` builds a full `sf` object (which has also a `data.frame` class) which is a data frame with a geometry column. In the given example there is no data attached to the polygon (no attributes). You can attach data by building a data.frame :

```
poly <- st_sf(data.frame(landuse = "Forest", 
                         size = 23 , 
                         st_sfc(st_polygon(list(as.matrix(df))))), 
              crs = 4326)
poly
## ## Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 2 fields
## geometry type:  POLYGON
## dimension:      XYZ
## bbox:           xmin: 1 ymin: 119.4 xmax: 5 ymax: 119.5
## epsg (SRID):    4326
## proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
## landuse size                       geometry
## 1  Forest   23 POLYGON Z ((1 119.4 -5.192,...
```

You can then extract each of these elemnts form the spatial object and check their class :

Full sf object : a data.frame with a sfc geometry column

```
class(poly)
## "sf"         "data.frame"
```

Third column extracted as a list : sfc object

```
class(poly[[3]])
## "sfc_POLYGON" "sfc"
```

First element of the geometry column : an sfg polygon object

```
class(poly[[3]][[1]])
## "XY"      "POLYGON" "sfg"
```

Comment: I was able to accomplish the same thing without the `st_sf()`.  For example:  
`poly <- st_sfc(st_polygon(list(as.matrix(df))), crs = 4326)`
Can anyone explain what the difference is (I can't)?

Answer (score 3):

`library(sfheaders)` on CRAN from 20191004 can take a data.frame and convert it to `sf` objects

```
library(sf)
library(sfheaders)

df <- data.frame(
  lon = c(119.4, 119.4, 119.4, 119.5, 119.5),
  lat = c(-5.192, -5.192, -5.187, -5.187, -5.191)
)

sfheaders::sf_polygon(
  obj = df
)
## given only two columns of data are in df there's no need to specify lon & lat arguments

# Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 1 field
# geometry type:  POLYGON
# dimension:      XY
# bbox:           xmin: 119.4 ymin: -5.192 xmax: 119.5 ymax: -5.187
# epsg (SRID):    NA
# proj4string:    
#   id                       geometry
# 1  1 POLYGON ((119.4 -5.192, 119...
```

Comment: how can convert to polygon this column string ? "list(c(-72.6689780388482, -72.6697951984133, -72.670538307013, -72.6696918495337, -72.6689780388482, -37.8155440677891, -37.8164165487739, -37.815944377963, -37.8151004670485, -37.8155440677891))"

Answer (score 0):

I don't know "sf", but just in case you meant "sp", here is the complete construction of a SPDF

```
df <- data.frame(lon=c(119.4,119.4,119.4,119.5,119.5), 
             lat=c(-5.192,-5.192,-5.187,-5.187,-5.191))

require(sp)
spdf <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(
  SpatialPolygons(
    Srl=list(
      Polygons(srl=list(
        Polygon(coords=df)
      ), ID=1)
    )
  ),
  data=data.frame(a=1)
)

plot(spdf)
```