# R - make simple features from a data.frame, by ID

Tags: r, geometry, polygon, r-sf

I am getting myself in a muddle with `sf` in R; I am trying to create a collection of features, from a large data frame of coordinates.

My data is a `data.frame` of x and y coordinates, and the ID determines their grouping (i.e. all the same ID is one polygon). I would like to take this and create a sf collection;

```
# create some dummy data, coordinates for 3 squares (v. similar to provided data)
df <- data.frame(x = c(0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5), y = c(1,2,2,1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2,1), ID = rep(1:3, each = 4))

# split into a list, by ID, ready for conversion to WKT coordinate strings
split_list <- split(df, df$ID)

# the data provided does not complete the polygon, i.e. it must end with the same coordinates
# it begins with - add it in by replicating first row
split_list <- lapply(split_list, function(x) rbind(x,x[1,]))

# remove the ID column
split_list <- lapply(split_list, function(x) {x["ID"] <- NULL; x})

# create the geometry type, st_polygons (convert to matrix in the list)
o <- st_polygon(lapply(split_list,function(x) as.matrix(x)  ))

# promote to an sfc, with CRS
b_sfc <- st_sfc(o, crs = "+init=epsg:4326")

# create an data frame for the polygons
bdf <- data.frame(ID = 1:length(o), val = sample(1:1000,length(o), replace = T), row.names = NULL)

# create an sf collection of 3 polygons
pols_sf <- st_sf(bdf, geometry = b_sfc)

# on the surface it seems complete:
Simple feature collection with 3 features and 2 fields
geometry type:  POLYGON
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 0 ymin: 1 xmax: 5 ymax: 2
epsg (SRID):    4326
proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
   ID val                       geometry
1  1 262 POLYGON ((0 1, 0 2, 1 2, 1 ...
2  2  59 POLYGON ((0 1, 0 2, 1 2, 1 ...
3  3 754 POLYGON ((0 1, 0 2, 1 2, 1 ...

# but each feature has the geometries for every polygon?
pols_sf[1,]$geometry

Geometry set for 1 feature 
geometry type:  POLYGON
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 0 ymin: 1 xmax: 5 ymax: 2
epsg (SRID):    4326
proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
POLYGON ((0 1, 0 2, 1 2, 1 1, 0 1), (2 1, 2 2, ...

# and especially;
st_coordinates(pols_sf[1,])

   X Y L1 L2
   0 1  1  1
   0 2  1  1
   1 2  1  1
   1 1  1  1
   0 1  1  1
5  2 1  2  1
6  2 2  2  1
7  3 2  2  1
8  3 1  2  1
51 2 1  2  1
9  4 1  3  1
10 4 2  3  1
11 5 2  3  1
12 5 1  3  1
91 4 1  3  1
```

How do i make each simple feature just have the geometry of 4 corners? (5 coordinate pairs)

Comment: See the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61264147/7547327

Comment: cheers, i'll have a look into that, i'd still really like to know what i'm doing wrong - i think it's to do with not making a list of st_polygons, but i'll look into it over the weekend

Answer (score 0):

I believe the necessary result is achievable using a combination of `dplyr::summarize()` to turn your points into multipoints according to the value of your ID column, and then `sf::st_cast()`-ing these into polygons.

By the way: the shape of your polygons does not look quite right, and you may also consider `sf::st_convex_hull()` to make them truly square (if that was your intent).

I am using your initial data, only replacing the numeric ids with letters.

```
library(dplyr)
library(sf)

# create some dummy data, coordinates for 3 squares (v. similar to provided data)
df <- data.frame(x = c(0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5), 
                 y = c(1,2,2,1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2,1), 
                 ID = rep(letters[1:3], each = 4),
                 stringsAsFactors = T)

# make the data frame spatial (as points)
src <- st_as_sf(df, coords = c("x", "y"))

# intermediary check
plot(src, pch = 4)
```

[image: check]

```
# from points to multipoints & finally polygons
res <- src %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise() %>%
  st_cast("POLYGON")

# report results
plot(res)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer, i am interested as to why you dont think my dummy data are squares? I mean, my real data are odd non-regular parallelograms, but i simplified. Also, your method seems to produce bow-ties :)

Comment: My first idea - when looking at the image #1 - was that your data were squares, and thus I was surprised by the bow ties. Which are of course consequences of point order. As I have no idea about your actual data I thought it reasonable to suggest st_convex_hull, which is on one hand convect (concaveman::concaveman could give you concave hull) but on the other hand not dependent on ordering and thus somewhat more robust.

Comment: they are squares, and the point order goes from bottom left, top left, top right, bottom right. I dont think st_cast knows how to respect the order after conversion to points.

Comment: then you can consider replacing the st_cast("polygon") by a st_convex_hull() call and the squares could not be any prettier